# php laravel get all and append on the first position

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

In a controller, I do this

```
$categories = Category::lists('name', 'id');
$categories['-1'] = 'Select Category';
```

then in a view, I do this:

```
{{Form::select('category_id', $categories, '', $categories)}}
```

The result HTML is:

```
    <select apartment="Apartment" car="Car" select="" category="Select Category" name="category_id">
<option value="2">Apartment</option>
<option value="3">Car</option>
<option value="-1">Select Category</option>
</select>
```

is there any way to make the `Select Category` appears as the first option?

**I know that problem happens because I add the `-1` entity after getting the other values, but I couldn't know how to solve it**

Comment: Assuming ids > 0, simple `array_unshift($categories, 'Select Category');` will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$categories = array('' => 'Select Category') + Category::lists('name', 'id');
```

This will work.